# Complex analysis beginning of integration

Tags: complex-analysis

please could you help me with another steps in my calculation? I will write what I have found out till now. :)

Consider the integral I. provide some upper bound for I using the properties of complex integrals:

where $I = \frac{z^{11}f(z)}{100-z}dz, f(z) = (1 - 2Im(z))$ and Lis the lower part of the circle $|z - 1| = 1$.

My idea is using this parametrization: $z(t) = z_0 + Re^{it}$, where $z_0 = R = 1$. Because it is a parametrization for the circle. Then we get $x(t) = R cos(t), dx = -Rsin(t) dt, y(t) = R sin(t), dy = Rcos(t) dt, so |dz| = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = 1dt $.

Because for upper bound is the pattern:

$I \leq \int_L |h(z)| * |dz|$, where $|dz| = dt$.

Now I will put it into the pattern, please could you check the boundaries of integral :)

$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} |\frac{(1 + e^{it})^{11} * (1 - 2 sin(t)) }{100-1-e^{it}}| * dt$.

And now I do not know hoe to calculate $|h(z)|$, $(1+ e^{it})$ is probably an affine map, but I do not know how to do it'S power. Do you know?

The another perhaps how to calculate upper boun of the inregral I is to use the pattern:

$|\int_L h(z) dz| \leq MP$, where $M \geq |h(z)|$ on $L$ and P is the length of L.
$P = \int _a^b \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} dt = |dz|, z = 1 + e^{it} = 1 + cos(t) + i*sin(t), dx = -sin(t) dt, dy = cos(t) dt, \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \pi$.

And we get:

$|\int_L h(Z) dz| \leq \int_L MP = \int_L MP = \int{\pi}{2\pi} M \pi$.

I hope that $\pi$ and $2\pi$ are chosen correctly but the main problem is that now I do not know how to calculate M.

Would you advice me how to calculate some upper bound for $I$? You can choose one of these patterns or something else, if you know.

Comment: You’ll receive a much better response if you take the time to learn how to type your homework rather than posting an image of it (I understand that it is difficult when you first start typing, but it makes the mathematics much easier to read as well as attracts more helpful contributors).

Comment: Also, is there a specific step in the calculation that you’re unsure of?

Comment: I understand, i like it much more too, but this time I was really careful in writing it to a paper. :)

Comment: Yes, firs I am unsure of parametrization and in boundaries which I change ($pi$ and $2pi$). Then in calculation of integral. First I thing that method per partes will be better, but the result was stupid and then I recognized this easy method, but it is my first time when I integrate a complex function and I am not sure in all this process. I hope that the function is analytic, to it could have a primitive function. I will be happy for any advice. I am iterested in this topic but totally lost in it and I do not know where to find out it.